# navigation navigate outside appcontainer in app.js

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Current Behavior

I use react navigation v4x
undifined is not an object navigation.discpatch

Expected Behavior

I want to navigate login page in appcontainer
`

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isFirstLaunch: false, hasCheckedAsyncStorage: false};
    const myRef = createRef();
  }

  onPressLogin() {
    this.navigator.dispatch(
      NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })
    );
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const isFirstLaunch = await checkIfFirstLaunch();
    this.setState({isFirstLaunch, hasCheckedAsyncStorage: true});
  }

  render() {
    const {hasCheckedAsyncStorage, isFirstLaunch} = this.state;

    if (!hasCheckedAsyncStorage) {
      return null;
    }
    return isFirstLaunch ? (
      <EntryInfo onPress={this.onPressLogin} />
    ) : (
      <AppContainer
        ref={nav => {
          setTopLevelNavigator(nav);
          this.navigator = nav;
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}`
```

software version android
react-navigation    4.4.0
react-navigation-stack  2.8.2
react-native    0.62.2

Comment: You to follow this guide https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigating-without-navigation-prop.

Comment: ı tried to solution but it did not work :/

Comment: your code does not seems like it is following the guide...

Comment: _navigationService.default.navigate is not an object

Comment: can you post your full app.js and NavigationService?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure navigator exist before navigate. It works for m

```
function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
if(navigatorRef)
{
   navigator = navigatorRef;
}
  
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
  if(navigator && routeName){
   navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    })
  );
  }
  
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  navigate,
  setTopLevelNavigator,
};
```